# downloading and showing PDFs from URLs placed in database

Tags: java, android

I have a list of books in my application. their format is PDF and every PDF has an URL in database, the app has an activity in which there is a button for going to download activity, when I want to download and show all PDFs for the first time, every thing is true but for the second time, something that happens is showing the last PDF that has been downloaded for all books. I do not know why!
here is my code:

```
 public  class ShowDastan extends Activity {
    public static String file_url;
    public static String filename;
    Dastan dastan;
    Context c;
    DBAdapter db;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_dastan);
        c = getBaseContext();
        db = new DBAdapter(c);
        db.open();
        dastan = (Dastan) getIntent().getExtras().get("thisdastan");
        final Button btn_download =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_download);
        file_url=dastan.getAddress();
        filename=dastan.getPdfname();
        btn_download.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ShowDastan.this, Download.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        db.updateContact(dastan);
        db.close();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        db.open();
    }
}
```

Dawnload Activity:

```
public class Download extends Activity{
    String path;
    private  ProgressDialog pDialog;
    ShowDastan showDastan;
    public static final int progress_bar_type = 0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.download);
       new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(showDastan.file_url);
    }
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case progress_bar_type:
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                pDialog.setMessage("downloading...please waite");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setMax(100);
                pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
                return pDialog;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
    class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(progress_bar_type);
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 10000);

                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/" + showDastan.filename);
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);
           ShowPDF();

        }
    }
    public void ShowPDF(){
        path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + showDastan.filename;
        File file = new File(path);
        Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
        target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: So the first time all PDFs are downloaded and displayed and the second time all PDFs are downloaded again, but only the last one is displayed for all books? Or is nothing downloaded the second time?

Answer (score 0):

PDF in android can view above android version N..

Answer (score 0):

use this in `showPdf()`:

```
String[] paths={path};
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, paths, null, null);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. I do not know why for second time, I mean after downloading and viewing all PDFs correctly, for every book, just the last PDF that had been downloaded is shown

Comment: @ava i do not understand your problem. second time what is downloaded same files? or another files?